# creating a folder and verifying that the path is ok

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a folder in my VB .NET app but I can't get to verify that the path is correct. For example, if I enter

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("lol it will work")
```

It works... While it doesn't look like a folder path at all... How can I verify that the path entered is correct ? And since it doesn't throw any exception, the folder must be created somewhere, but where ? I can't find it...

Thank you

Comment: Please read about an application's "current working directory". Also there is nothing invalid about that directory name.

Comment: You could change the title of your question like _"How to know if the use of relative I/O paths were correctly resolved"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Directory name "lol it will work" ***is*** a valid name.

When you don't provide an explicit path, My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory() (as well as some other methods/functions) will assume the string you provided is the path to a directory which ***relative path*** is your Application's **current directory.**

So it doesn't matter whether you're passing a complete path *(that looks like a valid folder path)* or a **partial** path/folder name that will be associated with the application's Directory as long as :

- the **resolved** Path is a valid path (that doesn't contains invalid chars or missing folder name separator)
- you (your application) have access to that path
- the resulting path doesn't exceed the max allowed number of characters.
- you don't encounter some specific Exceptions...

---

So, how do you know your application current working path ?

Since you used My.Application.FileSystem :

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory ' Read/Write Property As String
```

You can use System.IO :

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ' Get a String
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(NewPath) ' Set
```

You can also use System.Environment.Directory

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory ' Read/Write Property As String
```

Both three (My.Computer.FileSystem, System.IO.Directory and Environment) are writable, and returns the current directory to be resolved in case you're providing relative paths in your application.

---

> #### So, to answer your question : *"How can I verify that the path entered is correct ?"*

If you just created the Directory and you get no exception, then the name of your (relative) directory is valid, and the directory has been created :

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("lol it will work")
' Verification :
If System.IO.Directory.Exists("lol it will work") Then
    MessageBox.Show("The Directory has been created !")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The Directory has'n been created !")
End If
' Shows "The Directory has been created !"
```

So you know that even other Functions/Methods can resolve relative path (not all though) by fallbacking to the defined Relative Working Path of your Application.

The test above is the same as :

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists( _
    Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "lol it will work"))
```

---

> ### CAUTION :
>
> Due to the writable nature of those objects, your application
> ***may*** change the Current Directory **any time**.

Consider :

- the use of alternative objects/variables to get your working directory or similar
- working with only explicit paths
- using a global/static variable that stores the CurrentDirectory upon startup (can fail very easily)
- restoring the CurrentDirectory whenever you're changing it (though you ***will*** use at a time or another an object that changes the CurrentDirectory without warning - read the documentation of that object whenever it involves a directory manipulation; OpenFileDialog for example which has different behaviours on XP and Win7/8) - This move is the least recommended.

---

### Alternates :

**AppDomain.CurrentDomain**

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

This is a ReadOnly Property. It returns the path to the directory your assembly (application) were loaded from. **Caution !** This path has a trailing `"\"` like :

```
G:\Tools\...\Sources\bin\Debug\   ' <- !!!
```

---

**Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location**

```
System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

This will also return the path to the directory the assembly were loaded from, but without the trailing `"\"` due to the use of `GetParent()`

Using `Assembly` to retrieve a path is useful when you're dealing with dependencies where not all Assemblies are loaded from the same directory. Codes that uses relative paths **should** use this approach instead of the classic ones.

---

I assume the same applies for Thread Domain if you want to get deep in multithreads (while I'm not really sure of the relevant aspect of this assumption - Never used this one !) :

```
Thread.GetDomain().BaseDirectory ' ReadOnly
```

---

And the good old `Application.StartupPath`

```
Application.StartupPath ' ReadOnly
```

...which also has a trailing `"\"`. You can't access StartupPath until the application has actually started ! However, I've never checked whether it's working well when you start another process from your application and using that through the other process... (if it's possible... just imagining though)

Comment: Omg such a good answer for such a simple question ^_^ thank you very much, I now understand exactly why it works while I thought it wouldn't. Now I wrote a function that will verify that it's a good absolute path. Thank you very much :) hope you didn't take too much to write all that.